Timefold -- How to add problem fact calculation to each solution calculation to get the corresponding deduction points
Before, when using optaplanner + drools, we can use insertLogical to create new instances with entity collection parameters & problem fact collection parameters to calculate multiple score points values basing on calculated instances results to determine how to deduct points,such as
rule "create pointscalculateinstance"
    when 
        $requestList :  ArrayList() from collect  (
        Request ()
        )  
        
        $stockList : ArrayList() from collect (
        Stock()
        )
        
        $taskList :  ArrayList() from collect  (
        Task (machine != null)
        )
    then
        insertLogical(new pointscalculateinstance($requestList,$stockList,$taskList));
        
    end


rule "point1 rule"
    when 
        $pointscalculateinstance : pointscalculateinstance ($point1 : point1)
        eval($point1 > 0)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $point1); 
    end

rule "point2 rule"
    when 
        $pointscalculateinstance: pointscalculateinstance($point2 : point2)
        eval($point2 > 0)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, $point2); 
    end

rule "point3 rule"
    when 
        $pointscalculateinstance : pointscalculateinstance($point3 : point3)
        eval($point3 > 0)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $point3); 
    end


pointscalculateinstance class such as:
public class pointscalculateinstance{ 

    private ArrayList<Request> requestList;
    private ArrayList<Stock> stockList;
    private ArrayList<Task> taskList;
    private int point1;  
    private int point2;  
    private int point3;  
    private int point4; 
    private int point5; 
    private int point6; 
    private int point7; 
    private int point8; 
    private int point9; 
    private int point10; 

Solution such as:
@PlanningSolution
public class Planning{

    
   @PlanningScore
   private HardMediumSoftScore  score;
    
   @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
   @ValueRangeProvider(id = "taskRange")
   private ArrayList<Task> taskList;
    
    
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "machineRange")
    private ArrayList<Machine> machineList;
    
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private ArrayList<Request> requestList;
    
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private ArrayList<Stock> stockList;

In fact, this is a chained model, due to special operational requirements, I need to calculate Stock consumption utilization corresponding to each solution based on the chained order of the task list;
Now when I refactor the project , how to achieve this when using timefold by constraint stream?
The only way I can think of is to use group by  + tolist(), but there are many constraints, repeatedly writing so many constraints for the same computational procedure is not a good idea
How to create new instances with entity collection parameters & problem fact collection parameters to calculate multiple score points values basing on calculated instances results to determine how to deduct points when using timefold

Please correctly format code, there are many parts of code that are not formatted.

You should be able to build that metadata directly on your domain objects using shadow variables. Penalization then flows naturally from that.
